# Is there any way to change the product version from major.minor.build to major.build.minor?

Tags: windows-installer

My product has version number major.minor.build (say 5.0.196). Now we are developing patches and that is to be added as a revision number as major.minor.build.revision(eg: 5.0.196.123 "123 is revision number"). As it is the property of msi that it wont consider the fourth field of product version, we are unable to use detect and upgrade the patches.
There is proposal as to change the product version as major.build.revision (5.196.123). 
Can we do that? If yes, How to do it and how does it effect the versioncheck for upgrades?

Comment: You are patching without rebuilding?

Comment: Yes pathching without rebuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include a fourth field in your product version, the installer ignores the fourth field.

For a patch package, the [Revision Number Summary property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifies the GUID patch code for the patch. This can be followed by a list of patch code GUIDs for obsolete patches that are to be removed when this patch is applied. The patch codes are concatenated with no delimiters separating GUIDs in the list.

If the updates you are proposing to make do qualify to be a [small update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/c74ef2bd-9cf5-4ec0-bfff-1fad0e17ba98) and do not warrant changing the [ProductVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/551fca7e-a827-482d-bc56-ff2fe5a17025), then change the Revision Number Property.

A Minor Upgrade can be delivered as a patch, but requires the ProductVersion to change. [ProductCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/33cedd37-0343-471c-ad4b-0db5f98d5894) does not need to change in this case.

The different types of Windows Installer updates are compared here: [Patching and Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/da946739-9efc-4bf0-8a9a-6f6ead3c4a34).